# How to find all the reachable labels in assembly files?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm working on programming a tool which aimed to separate assembly codes into different sections and labels. I'm trying to add a recursive mode.

If i'd like to print codes of one specific label and codes in the label content symbols of other labels, recursive mode should print labels referred to at the same time.
For Example:

```
.file sample.s
...
A:
    ...
    call B
    ...
B:
    ...
C:
    ...
```

For codes above, if i'd like to print codes in label A on recursive mode, codes in label A and B should be printed at the same time.
To do this, i have to find all the label reference symbol for each line.

Some of instructions may be important like `call`, `lea`, `jmp`. But it's not easy to list all the conditions.
Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to print all code reachable from a given label, except by returning further up the call tree?  (i.e. all other basic blocks of this function, all child functions, and tail-call siblings).

The normal / simplest way for execution to get from one label to another is so simply fall through.  Like

```
   mov ecx, 123
looptop:           ; do {
   ...
   dec ecx
   jnz looptop     ; }while(--ecx)
```

Unless the last instruction *before* the next label is an unconditional jump (like `jmp` or `ret`, but not `call` which can eventually return), you should also be following execution into that next block.  A `ret` should end processing, `jmp` could be followed if you want, `jnz` might fall through.

For conditional branches, you presumably need to follow both sides.

Trying to trace through indirect jumps after code loads a function-pointer into a register with a RIP-relative LEA or a MOV is probably too hard.  Do you really want to be able to trace `foo(callback_func, 123)` and be able to print the code for `foo` and the code it might call at `callback_func`?

If the arg is passed in a register (like x86-64 calling conventions) and it doesn't store it to the stack and reload it, then it's fairly easy to match that up with a `jmp rdi` after seeing there have been no intervening writes to RDI in between.  But if it is more complex, like a debug built storing RDI to the stack and reloading somewhere else, you basically need an x86-64 simulator to trace the values.

I think it might be better to not even attempt tracing through indirect jumps, rather than having something that sometimes works (simple cases), sometimes doesn't.  So probably you should forget about `lea`, unless you're thinking about dumping data declarations for static data referenced with LEA or MOV.

---

Some `int 0x80` or `syscall` are noreturn (e.g. `_exit`, or `sigreturn`), but most aren't.  The behaviour depends on the RAX/EAX value (and on the OS).  Usually EAX gets set pretty soon before a system call, so you might want to special case the noreturn ones, otherwise you'll fall through past an exit into other code that shouldn't necessarily execute.

Same applies for library function calls like `call exit`.

Comment: Sorry, i think you misunderstand something. I just want to extract codes related to the label out of the file. If it is possible, i'd like to seperately extract codes of single label and  move it to a new assembly file. By adding some  details(such as declarations of labels, begining symbol of sections) , i can assemble the code to executable files and analyse the label via dynamic debugging. That's why i'm trying to develop a recursive mode.

Comment: What troubles me is that the locations of labels are not fixed. So i'm trying to extract some key features. The purpose is to make programs  precisely find all the labels. 
Some of labels exist suprisingly. For Ex:
`mov ESI,OFFSET .L_4217b0`

Comment: @S1mple: Oh, so you are interested in static data.  In that case yeah, you'd want to look at label references as operands to non-branch instructions, including LEA but by no means limited to it.  I think most of what I wrote is still relevant, especially the parts about fall-through from one label to another.  It's going to be hard to analyze anything if you only have the top half of a loop that contained an `if` or something.

Comment: @S1mple:   I don't fully understand why it's more helpful to have a fragment isolated in a separate executable vs. just using `ld -e foobar` to make any given label the entry point, or just setting EIP = wherever during a debug session.  So I don't have a clear idea how much code you want to pull out for a given start point.

Comment: I have to admit that if we just aim to debug the codes in label, it is unnecessary to "have a fragment isolated in a seperate executable".  Because from the traditional view,  assembly codes are from advanced language code and the programmers know what their codes are doing. Just debug the details and that's enough.

Comment: But i'm working on a new region. The assembly code are disassembled from stripped binaries. And the assembly codes are integrated enough to be assembled back by assemblers (We called reassemble). The tools will supple considerable symbols when disaassembling. It means that it's not easy to match labels in assembly codes and binary one by one. So it will be more quick to start directly from assembly codes. Isn't it?

Comment: Moreover, seperated fragment debugging is not my destination. It is just one way to get more info about the function of each label. Once i knowed the function of labels, i'm able to reuse the assembly codes in specfic labels.  Then assemble the new assembly file which has added codes reused. I'm able to "expand functions from other Software". That's my ultimate goal.

Comment: @S1mple: Right, a disassembler has to invent label names for branch targets if none existed, if it wants to make asm that can be fed to an assembler.  (Like `objconv`.)  To use that as a starting-point for understanding the code while reverse-engineering, it might make sense to assemble that complete asm source you now have, so you can do asm-source-level debugging on that, and see those labels and line numbers when stepping / jumping around in the reassembled executable built from it.  Forget the original binary.

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary to separate out parts of that asm source, unless individual functions are so big that it's hard to keep track of which pieces all go together.  Except for large chunks that make up whole functions, I guess, if you're going to eventually maintain this.  (But I'd consider using a decompiler to get C, if the result can compile back into working code, before putting work into making it more human-friendly.  If not, if the code does stuff that a decompiler doesn't handle well, then yeah stick with asm.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243013/discussion-between-s1mple-and-peter-cordes).